# How do I set two divs on opposite sides of a webpage without other divs ending up inbetween?

Tags: html, css

I have a title and a menu and I want them to be in opposite corners of my webpage, kinda like this: http://www.google.com/drive

My website is http://www.vincestechsupport.com/home.html

I really appreciate any advice you can give. Thanks guys. Here is the code:

```css
#Title {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: red;
  font-family: arial;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
#Title a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
#Menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  width: 500px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
#Menu {
  font-size: 30px;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  font-family: arial;
  width: 100%
}
#Menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
#Menu li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="Menu">
  <center>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home.html" title="Home"><b>Home</b></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="services.html" title="Services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="experience.html" title="Experience">Experience</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="pricing.html" title="Pricing">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contactme.html" title="Contact Me">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </center>
</div>

<div id="Title">
  <h1>
    <a href="http://www.vincestechsupport.com/home.html" title="Home">Vince&#8217;s Tech Support</a>
  </h1>
</div>

<div id="Home">
  <h1>Home</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After floating you should clear.

1.First method is adding "clearfix" class to `<div id="wrapper">` - `<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">`

and adding this style:

```
.clearfix:after { content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0; }
```

2.Second method is adding a height to `<div id="wrapper">`

3.And third method is adding `width:100%; overflow: hidden;` to `<div id="wrapper">`

You should choose but the best method is the first one with clearfix.